# How do you disable an extension in VSCode while developing it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am learning to develop an extension and I wanted to execute some code in the deactivate() function to see how it works, but when I run the extension I can't find the extension loaded in the Extensions menu so I can't disable it in this new window.

How do I disable the extension in the new window that opens when you run the extension?

**EDIT:** With Lex Li's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65481845/5744858) I managed to make a breakpoing hit, but after a couple of seconds the debugging session ends. Is there any way to not lose the debugging session?

Comment: `vsce package` to generate a .vsix file and then install it manually. BTW, rarely you see an extension uses `deactivate`.

Comment: @LexLi I knew I could use that approach, I just thought that there must be another better way. Besides, you can't debug it that way.

Comment: One idea is to extract your deactivate code into a separate function (which the deactivate() function calls), but also make it callable by another means, for example via a key combination.  That way it should be easy to debug the logic.  You'd comment out the alternate means for production.

Comment: For those interested in this problem, I opened a Github issue in the VSCode's repository with a feature request. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/171338

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no convenient option to deactivate your extension, there is an option to disable a specific extension or all of the installed extensions, but it means they wouldn't be available on the next entry, and I assume that is not what you are looking for.

[these are all the available built-in extension commands you can use:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9ote.png)

you can use all of the commands listed above from your extension using the vs code API, just go to your desired command and click on the settings icon on the right, and then right-click on the line of the command and click copy command ID.
example of command id that represents closingSidebar ---> "workbench.action.closeSidebar".
Then you can copy the command id into executeCommand function, example of a custom refresh command:

```
context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.commands.registerCommand('extensionName.refresh', async () => {
        await vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.closeSidebar");
        await vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.view.extension.sidebar-view");
    })
);
```

Using this method, you can use a custom command to mimic similar behavior. this is an example of how you can implement a custom command for your extension so it'll disable all the extensions and call the deactivate function.

```
context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.commands.registerCommand('extensionName.deactivate', async () => {
        await vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.extensions.action.disableAll");
        deactivate();
);
```

After that you will have to add the custom function to the package.json under "activationEvents" and "commands":

commands section example:

```
{
    "command": "extensionName.deactivate",
    "category": "extensionName",
    "title": "deactivate"
  },
```

activationEvents section example:

```
"activationEvents": [
"onCommand:extensionName.deactivate"]
```

now you can simply call this function from the command prompt by typing "> extensionName: deactivate" and test your deactivate code.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

Actually you don't need any extra steps (like disabling it somewhere).

Simply set a break point in `deactivate` and then close the folder that activates the extension (or the whole VSCode instance being debugged). Closing that will shut down your extension, step into `deactivate` and hit the break point.

Comment: Your answer does work, but after some seconds the debugging session ends so you can't stay an undefinited amount of time debugging.

Comment: I also faced the issue that stopping/restarting fails to stop on any breakpoints in `deactivate()` or `Disposable` callbacks. There is an old issue on the VSCode tracker saying that this works (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1298#issuecomment-291816435) but it clearly doesn't. At least under my circumstances. Sometimes the breakpoint blinks for a second but then it looks like VSCode proceeds killing the extension dev host process forcefully.
Same with `console.log()` — some logs appear in the console for a second before restars cleans it up.